# How can I draw bar graph from the data in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to draw a bar graph in MATLAB that represents players versus years won. For instance,

```
______________________________________
Country         Years won
______________________________________
US           2012, 2013
Canada        2012, 2013, 2017
Belgium      2002, 2004,2013, 2017
Hungary      2001, 2002, 2014, 2014
```

How can I draw the bar of this data values in MATLAB? I was wondering if someone could help me?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to plot a bar plot of the *number* of wins of each country you can do something like:

```
% country names cell array
Names = {'US','Canada','Belgium','Hungary'};
% years won cell array
YearsWon = {[2012, 2013],[2012, 2013, 2017],...
    [2002, 2004,2013, 2017],[2001, 2002, 2014, 2014]};
% number of years won
nWins = cellfun(@numel,YearsWon);
% bar plot
bar(nWins);
% set x&y tick labels
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', Names, 'XTickLabelRotation', -45,...
    'YTick', 0:max(nWins));
% set x&y axes labels
xlabel('Country Name'); ylabel('Years Won')
```

[image]